# Имя "pipenv" не распознано как имя командлета

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, pipenv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках путь к нему указан, в Path есть путь к папке, в которой находится pipenv (я даже путь к самому файлу pipenv в Path указал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это в настройках PyCharm указано, а система не знает, где этот executable находится. Добавьте путь PATH.

Comment: @void, как оказалось я добавил путь в PATH в разделе "переменные среды пользователя", а нужно было ещё это сделать в разделе в разделе "системные переменные"
Оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий, как ответ, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путь до команды в настройках PyCharm указан только, но сама система не знает, где этот executable находится. Добавьте путь до него в PATH системы.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это:

`py -m pipenv`

А так же можешь посмотреть [инструкцию по установке pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv)

Comment: пишет: Имя "py" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы

Comment: Спасибо, Ваша инструкция (по ссылке) оказалась очень полезной

Comment: я ставил эту галочку, когда устанавливал (команда "python --version" работает корректно)